# How to ease-in y velocity of a game object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a game object, and on a button press, I'm adding velocity on `y` axis, so the character jumps up... and this works as expected.

```
public float jumpForce

private void Jump()
{
    playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(playerRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    AudioManagerController.instance.PlaySfx(Util.AudioEffect.PlayerJump);
}
```

However, this is pretty linear, the player jumps up with constant speed. I'd like to change it so that the player initially jumps up slow, gradually (exponentially? quickly? not sure what the right word is here) gains height quicker the longer the button is pressed.

Kind of like an ease-in:

[image]

I've tried increasing the velocity from `0` to `jumpForce` in `update()`, similar to:

```
jumpModifier = time.deltaTime; // In start()
...
jumpModifier = jumpModifier + time.deltaTime; // in update()
```

I've tried a few variations of these and it doesn't quite do what I want it to do.

How do I make my character jump up in an ease-in sort of way please?

Answer (score 0):

EaseIn curve is the Cos+Lerp curve, or the "Coserp".

```
//Ease in
public static float Coserp(float start, float end, float value)
{
    return Mathf.Lerp(start, end, 1.0f - Mathf.Cos(value * Mathf.PI * 0.5f));
}

public static Vector2 Coserp(Vector2 start, Vector2 end, float value)
{
    return new Vector2(Coserp(start.x,end.x,value),Coserp(start.y,end.y,value));
}

public static Vector3 Coserp(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, float value)
{
    return new Vector3(Coserp(start.x, end.x, value), Coserp(start.y, end.y, value), Coserp(start.z, end.z, value));
}
```

Comment: This works if I know the `end` vector - in my case, I don't! I need to be able to incrememt the `velocity.y` value (only) softly at first, and quickly as the time goes on... but i'll try to adopt this to my needs and see if it works

Comment: Okay, I was just about to try this out and read the code - I can tell this code won't work without even trying it for two reasons: 1) the inner recursive function is passing float values to main functions whereas the main one takes a vector (2) (I'm less sure about this one, but...) this is a recursive function with no exit condition! I will thank you for the general idea though, I'll look up on cos + lerp curve and see what I can do. Thanks.

Comment: @LocustHorde I've updated the answer, it was late and I forgot the main code of the answer *facepalm. Check it out now.